# Redirect page return certification failure

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect the login.htm to index.htm. but after executing the `Response.Redirect`, it returns an error certification failure. and If I click that this is the message.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter: users not found.
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

This is my authentication code.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void LogMeIn(string users, string pass) {

        try
        {
            // string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE userName = '" + users + "' AND passWord ='" + pass + "'";
            string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE userName = @user AND passWord = @pass";
            int count = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection thisConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmdCount = new MySqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
                {
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", users);
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCount.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/default/index.htm", false);                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException tEx)
        {
            // Do nothing. ASP.NET is redirecting.
            // Always comment this so other developers know why the exception 
            // is being swallowed.
            Console.WriteLine(tEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log other types of exception.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: one can't "swallow" ThreadAbortException... but indeed all "other developers" know that.

Comment: You also should review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - since you (likely incorrectly based on the error message) claiming that exception happens *after* call to `Redirect` you should show how that destination url is handled - please [edit] post to show just necessary code (you can safely remove all SQL code - the fact you figured out proper way of parametrizing query is nice, but does not seem to be related to your problem)